# AWS EC2 reserved instance with no upfront

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, reserved-instances

I have purchased few 1 year no-upfront reserved instances, say 3x c4.large Windows instances, it cost $0.199 hourly each.

But now, I need only 1x c4.large instance, so there are 2 reserved instance wasted, how will AWS bill me these instances ? still have 6 months left.

Sorry for stupid question, I have search AWS docs but still confusing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not Amazon's billing department.

Comment: There're no linux department, no windows department, no apache department, vote down to close the community also ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be billed monthly for all the instances you reserved for 12 consecutive months. It doesn't matter if you use them or not.

If you want to resell your reserved instances, you can take a look at the [Reserved Instance Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/reserved-instances/marketplace/). Restrictions apply. See link.

Comment: I don't have US bank account, seems I better to rearrange the VM allocation to use that reserved instance... thank you :)